# Map flag doesn't seem to work in manifest file

Tags: microsoft-ajax-minifier, ajaxmin

My arguments node looks like:

```
<arguments>-clobber -map:v3 app\script.min.js.map</arguments>
```

My min file is: `script.min.js` and the output node is: `<output path="app\script.min.js">`

I also tried the path with quotes in it but it didn't make a difference. Not sure if this is a bug or whether I'm configuring my flags incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the issue. i was using an argument when i was supposed to use the "symbolMap" child node under the "output" node, like so:
`<symbolMap name="v3" path="app\script.min.js.map" />`